# First and last values in html table won't be recognised

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have spent a large amount of time trying to figure this out but for some reason the value for the first rows first cell won't match (I am checking the rows id number).

I have checked with an alert that its id number is being called, which it is, but it still won't go into the if statement even though all the other rows do.

Also the last item in the table doesn't get called and when I increase the length of the table but incrementing count by on an error occurs. Variable a starts on 1 to avoid the columns heading it. (No difference is made when it is 0). It is as though the first row and last row are just ignored.

```
          var warray = data.split(",");

          var count = document.getElementById('wtable').getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
          var table = document.getElementById('wtable');


           for(var i = 0; i < warray.length; i++){

                var waiting = warray[i].split("|");
                var check = true;
                for(var a = 1; a < count; a++){

                           var rowid = table.rows[a].cells[0].innerHTML;

                           if(rowid == waiting[0]){
                               alert("here");
                               var x = document.getElementById("wtable").rows[a].cells;
                               x[2].innerHTML = waiting[2];
                               check = false;
                               break;
                       }
                }
                // only need to add new row if item doesnt exist
                if(check){....
```

To help show my code this is how I create the table....

```
<table id="wtable" class="waiting-table" cellpadding="11"><tr>.   <th>Order ID</th><th>Customer</th><th>Vendor</th><th>Address</th>.   <th>Cart_ID</th><th>Cart</th><th>Checked</th></tr>

<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($waiting)){

echo "<tr id=".$row[0].">";
echo '<td>',$row[0],'</td>';
echo '<td>',$row[1],'</td>';
echo '<td>',$row[4],'</td>';
echo '<td>',$row[8],'</td>';
echo '<td>',$row[2],'</td>';
echo '<td>',"items",'</td>';
?>
  <td>
    <button onclick='orderPacked("<?php echo $row[0]; ?>","<?php echo $row[2]; ?>","<?php echo $row[4]; ?>")'id="buttonpacked"  name="packed" >Packed</button>
   </td>
  </tr>
 <?php } ?>

</table>
```

Comment: `var a = 0` perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change second for.

```
var a = 0; a <= count; a++
```

Comment: It starts on 1 to avoid the heading still don't get noticed when is on 0.

Comment: I get this error with the added "<="  - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'table.rows[a].cells') basically the 1st row and last row are totally ignored

Comment: I'm not really great at Javascript but what happens if you change `var code = document.getElementById('wtable').rows.length;` and run the code like this ?

Comment: No gives me the same length (number) of rows

Answer (score 1):

```
(...)
for(var a = 1; a < count; a++){
                       var rowid = table.rows[a].cells[0].innerHTML;
(...)
```

table.rows starts at index 0. You're only reading the indexes starting at a's initial value, which is 1.

change it to:

```
(...)
for(var a = 0; a < count; a++){
                       var rowid = table.rows[a].cells[0].innerHTML;
(...)
```